# setInterval увеличивает свою скорость при каждом нажатии на кнопу

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как сделать что бы **setInterval** не увеличивал свою скорость ?

Вот есть функция

```
  const mozgi_1 = useCallback(
    () => {
      setNum_zombe(num_zombe + dromPointMozgi)
      if(num_z1 >= 1) {
        setNum_z1(num_z1 -1)
        let mozgi1 = document.getElementById('mozgi1');
        mozgi1.classList.remove('__obj___mozgi-block')
      }
    },
    [num_zombe, dromPointMozgi, num_z1],
  )
```

она привязана за кнопкой и ее же отрабатывает **setInterval**

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setInterval( 
      mozgi_1
  , 600);
  }, [mozgi_1])
```

Все нормально до того времени пока я не начну нажимать на кнопку после каждого нажатия **setInterval**  работает все быстрее и быстрее. Как это исправить?

Comment: Каждый раз когда вы нажимаете кнопку вы добавляете новый `setInterval`. Когда их много, вам кажется что он один, просто работает быстрее. Не создавайте много `setInterval`.

Comment: уже понял, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем примере, при каждом изменении значения mozgi_1(вызове) вызывался useEffect, который повторно запускал таймер

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const time = setInterval(
    mozgi_1
    , 600);

  return () => {
    clearInterval(time);
  }
}, []);
```

Т.е. вам надо убрать зависимости из useEffect, тогда он сработает один раз при загрузке.

Если компонент будет отмонтирован, то интервал остановится

Comment: а мне и нужно что бы он всегда отрабатывал

Comment: ну вроде все работает